# Extract data from div tag that was created on runtime

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Actually I am trying to parse div but I don't know why the code is not working. Here it is:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(this.Page.MapPath("~/Default2.aspx"));

HtmlNodeCollection bodyNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='wrapper']/a[@href]");
foreach (var node in bodyNodes)
{
    string href = node.Attributes["href"].Value;
}
```

BodyNodes are empty. May be because it only has content on runtine otherwise it's empty. How to get div data on runtime?

Comment: Loading like that just loads the original aspx document from disk. I think you need LoadHtml or something.

Comment: Yes but I dont know how to do that. I have searched a lot about how to load current html file in doc but did not find any solution.

Comment: This is the help for LoadHtml
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Loads the HTML document from the specified string.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   html:
        //     String containing the HTML document to load. May not be null.
        public void LoadHtml(string html);

Comment: I by using doc.HtmlLoad("~Default2.aspx") ,, I am still getting null bodyNodes. I really need help  :(